# Spring - Provide parsed JWT as Resource method parameter

Tags: spring, jwt

In Spring framework, is there a way to parse JWT and provide it's data as one of the Resource method parameters?

Something like this:

```
class MyJwtToken {
    String fieldA;
    Integer fieldB;
}

public ResponseEntity<> create(
  @JwtToken MyJwtToken token,
  @RequestBody Item item
) {
  item.setFieldA(token.getFieldA());
  persist(item);
  return ...;
}
```

Comment: Why not provide it as an injectable request-scope bean instead? Simpler, doesn't clutter the method signature, and injectable everywhere and not just from resource methods.

Comment: @JBNizet That sounds great to me. Where can I start looking to do that?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-other

Comment: @JBNizet That worked like a charm, but I am trying to find a way to access it from the singleton RestController. In a mean time I extended the principal user object with parsed token data (using `SecurityConfigurerAdapter`) and accessing it through `SecurityContextHolder`.

Comment: If it's a bean, you can inject it in you controller.

Comment: Added proxy and worked nicely.